# String Alias id and int value can be added?

Tags: java, string, integer, addition

`String a=A000001;`
`String b = (A000001) + 1;`
`b=A000002;`

*I want to add two values. my 1st value is string alias and 2nd is int 1.*
**Is it possible?**

Comment: Treat the String as hex? Of course that would not work for K000000 + 1. Base36?

Comment: not get your point

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
String s = "(A000001) + 1";
String[] operands = s.split(" ");
int a = Integer.parseInt(operands[0].replaceAll("\\W", ""), 16);
int b = Integer.parseInt(operands[operands.length-1].replaceAll("\\W", ""), 16);
//Assume addition or you need to parse and identify the operator
int sum = a + b;
System.out.println(Integer.toString(sum, 16).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: That's another question entirely. Please accept the answer to this one and ask another

Answer (score 0):

or just use them as ints
and format the ints as hexadecimals.
Makes it easier to increase the values.

```java
        int a = 0xA000001;
        int b = a + 1;
        System.out.printf("%X", b);
```

Comment: need to a variable type is string